# MS Excel: INDIRECT with an ! (exclamation) followed by some string name

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I am new to excel macros I am trying to get my head around the macros. I have figured out that

```
=INDIRECT(A1 & "!D1")
```

will reference to `A1` cell and then look for that sheetname and find its `D1` cell. For example, I have a sheet named `shan` with `D1` call as 22, and if `A1` cell has `shan` , So I get `22`.

But, the sheet I am referring to has a formula

```
INDIRECT(G$43 & "!summaryval")
```

I cant find `summaryval` anywhere in the MS excel sheet. What is this `!summaryval` referring to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `Named Range` on the destination sheet.  For example:

[image]

Where *Sheet1* is like:

[image]

Note:

Cell **I3** on *Sheet1* has been given the `Name` *summaryval*.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for quick reply

Answer (score 0):

**Formula (Ribbon) -> Name Manager** (or **Ctrl + F3**) lists all of the defined named ranges and the addresses they are referring to.